# Object to JSON angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this method

```
function submit() {      
        var JSONObject = {
             "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email,
             "review":$rootScope.review
        };
       debugger;
        var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSONObject);
    }
```

which I want to post to database later and I get error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0**

As I understood I get incorrect JSON format as my console.log input shows :
Object {name: "hh", surname: "hh", email: "kal@gmail.com", review: "fre"}

Instead it should show : `"name": "hh"` info like this right? How do I change that?

Comment: The format on console.log appears to be normal, because you're printing a Object with a "JSON name", not a real json. You're getting the error on the service posting, right?

Comment: Use before posting JSON.stringify(JSONObject)

Comment: Yes, I try to pass info to my UniversalService where my htt.post method is and I get this error

Comment: Can you provide the UniversalService.PostReview code?

Comment: `function PostReview(JSONObject) {
        debugger;
                 $http.post('http://localhost:8000/creation', JSONObject).then(function(){
            });
        }`

Comment: Try this way, just for clarify an doubt of mine: $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
    method: "POST",
    data: JSONObject,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
});

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: What it prints of JSONObject with console.log inside the UniversalService.PostReview?

Comment: Output: `Object {name: "hh", surname: "hh", email: "kaltenytmonika3@gmail.com", review: "hh"}`

Method: `  function PostReview(JSONObject) {
        debugger;
        
        if(JSONObject!=null){
             $http({ 
                 url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
                 method: "POST",
                 data: JSONObject,
                 headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;", "Accept": "application/json" } });
       debugger;
       console.log(JSONObject);
        }

        }`

Comment: My two cents: can this be a backend issue? AngularJS fails to parse http response if they're not in JSON format (unless you state this explicitly)

Comment: `public function created()
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
       // $request = json_decode($data);
        var_dump($data);
       // return $data;
        return response()->json($data);

    } `

This is my service method where I should get data from angular

Comment: It seems that everything is ok. As @Phugo said, i thought it could be a backend issue as well, but you're not even using the response for now, very weird. Anyway, try to check the request return before anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to stringify the post data like @Vivz suggested?

Comment: I do it like this and still get error :(

`function submit() {      
            var JSONObject = {
                 "name":$rootScope.name,
                 "surname":$rootScope.surname,
                 "email":$rootScope.email,
                 "review":$rootScope.review
            };
            debugger;
            JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
            var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSONObject);
        } `

Comment: JSON.stringify returns the "stringified" object without changing the source, try changing it to UniversalService.PostReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject)).

Comment: Try JSONObject=JSON.stringify(JSONObject) and then pass this to your API call